# How to debug Mojarra 2.2.9 in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsf, mojarra

I'm simply trying to debug Mojarra 2.2.9, I see the sources but when I'm trying to debug Mojarra, for example `UIInput.processUpdates`, it says "line not available" in the debug view, I still see the source but cannot navigate step by step into it.

Is it due to debug option used during compilation step in Mojarra, if yes, is there any way I can workaround this?

I'm using Tomcat 7 (so JSF not provided) and this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.9</version/>
</dependency>
```

Comment: or the runtime using a different version...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The best way to debug Mojarra and Primefaces in eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18512903/the-best-way-to-debug-mojarra-and-primefaces-in-eclipse)

Comment: Already read that post, the answer does not answer the problem actually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem does not happen in 2.2.8 and 2.2.10. This is what I thought, Mojarra 2.2.9 has been compiled without providing debug information, I guess it has been compiled with -g:source option. I'm wondering why? Well, it forces me to upgrade Mojarra then.

Comment: That's correct. It was a mistake during the build. Nonetheless, upgrading is always wise, 2.2.9 has its own set of other issues too. Current latest Mojarra version is 2.2.13.